# Facebook login button overlapping activity indicator when it's not supposed to. Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, button

I've implemented facebook login in my app and it's working fine. The problem is that I've also implemented an activity indicator to be in the center of the screen on top of the superview every time the user login either with facebook or email, and despite I've placed the facebook login button on the superview and bring the activity indicator to front of superview, it's overlapping the activity indicator at runtime. I've research a lot and didn't figure this out. 
My code:

```
let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addActivityIndicator(activityIndicator)
    setupFBloginButton()

}

func setupFBloginButton() {
    var fbLoginButtonConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    let buttonText = NSAttributedString(string: "Entrar com Facebook")
    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loginButton.removeConstraints(loginButton.constraints)
    loginButton.setAttributedTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)

    self.view.addSubview(loginButton)

    let leadingConstraint = loginButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10)
    let trailingConstraint = loginButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
    let heightContraint = loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
    let bottomConstraint = loginButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orLabel.topAnchor, constant: -20.0)
    fbLoginButtonConstraints.append(contentsOf: [leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint, bottomConstraint, heightContraint])

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(fbLoginButtonConstraints)
    loginButton.delegate = self
}

func addActivityIndicator(_ activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView) {

    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.10, blue:0.10, alpha:0.5)
    activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 70)
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)

}
```

As you can see, I've used bringSubview to the front of superview, but doesn't work anyway. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call bringSubviewToFront on the parent view.

```
 self.view.bringSubview(toFront:activityIndicator);
```

Comment: Of course! I've used this method in the wrong way, now I understand how it works. Thank you very much!